# How to make a Mac speak out system notifications?

Tags: mac, macos, accessibility, text-to-speech

Since a Mac can easily speak something, can it speak what is in a system notification?

Specifically, it is so that when a webpage displays a system notification, the text in the notification can be spoken out.

(P.S. the page OS X Yosemite: [Hear your Mac speak alert messages](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18730?locale=en_US) for alert won't work)